# Как сделать перенос строк, чтобы соседний слой не сжимался?

Tags: html, css

Возможно глупый вопрос, но так и не нашел простое решение.
Есть два слоя рядом друг с другом. У одного фиксированная ширина и, например, картинка. У другого текст.

Если во втором слое появляется текст с переносом строки, то первый слой почему-то сжимается.

Как победить это сжатие, не используя принудительную расстановку 
 и не фиксируя ширину второму слою?

```css
.main {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.imgWrapper {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="imgWrapper">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Очень длинный текст, самый длинный на свете
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Polyakivspb/pen/rrPgqw)

Comment: Это потому что у тя левый блок пустой

Comment: @Air, врядли. Добавил текст в левый блок, тоже самое https://codepen.io/Polyakivspb/pen/rrPgqw

Comment: А чего ты хочешь получить в итоге... ???  объясни нормально...

Comment: Что бы соседи были одинаковой ширины?

Comment: @Air  У левого блока установлена ширина 150px, но при сжатии он становится меньше 100px. Причин для такого сжатия нет — текст справа помещается.

Хочу, чтобы левый блок не сжимался.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задайте блоку `imgWrapper` свойство `flex-shrink: 0`.

Для родителя установленно свойство `display: flex`, блок с картинкой и текст являются flex-елементами, у них по дефолту заданны свойства

```
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: auto;
```

Если свойство `flex-basis` имеет значение `auto`, то его размер будет основываться на размере его контента или `width/height` если они установленны.
Но, работатют эти свойства(`width/height`) не так как для обычного блока.
В зависимости от установленных значений `flex-shrink` и `flex-grow` они будут вести себя как

```
min-width
max-width
min-height
max-height
```

В вашем примере у блока `imgWrapper` установлена ширина в `150px`, но дефолтные значение `flex-shrink` позволяет сжимать этот блок при необходимости. Исходя из этого если нужно добиться, что бы flex-елементы воспринимали ширину и высоту как обычный блок нужно выставить `flex-shrink: 0;` и `flex-grow: 0` (запретить изменять размер).

P.S. Высота упоминается здесь из за этого, что `flex-basis` считается по главной оси, а она, как мы знаем, может изменяться в зависимости от свойства `flex-direction`

Comment: Отлично, спасибо! 
А почему включается сжатие? На какую ширину оно происходит?